# Alert when user scrolls down to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is when user scrolls to bottom of div, to alert, it looks like it's only alerting when it's at top of page.  Not sure what's wrong:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/d8jot3sj/1/

```js
$(function(){
var content = $(".content");

 var box = $(".box");
 $(box).scroll(function(event) {  

 var box = $(".box");
if($(box).scrollTop() + $(box).height() == $(box).height()) {
alert('bottom');

}
});
$(".box").scroll(function(event){
var positionofscroll = $(this).scrollTop();

if(positionofscroll > 0){
content.stop().animate({
backgroundColor:"rgba(105, 63, 63, 0.69)"
},500);
}else {
content.stop().animate({
  backgroundColor:"red"
},500);

}
}); //scroll


});
```

```css
.box{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background:gray;
  overflow:auto;
}

.content{
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:1000px;
  background:red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Change background when user scrolls -->

<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    I'm content
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)  {
        alert('Reached at bottom');
}
```

inside of your **$(box).scroll(function(event){});**

Run this snippet

```js
$(function() {
  var content = $(".content");

  var box = $(".box");
  
  $(".box").scroll(function(event) {
    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
      alert('Reached at bottom');
    }
    
    var positionofscroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (positionofscroll > 0) {
      content.stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(105, 63, 63, 0.69)"
      }, 500);
    } else {
      content.stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }, 500);

    }
  }); //scroll


});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Change background when user scrolls -->

<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    I'm content
  </div>

</div>
```